# Can we recover a file after that part of the memory was allocated to another file?

Tags: image, ubuntu, data-recovery, file-recovery

I have deleted some pictures from my SD card and taken some more to the extent that it is almost full now. I was wondering if it is possible if I still can recover something from the past?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible for overwritten data. Nevertheless, you might recover some of the data from areas that *have not* been overwritten yet.

Sources:

- [Can Intelligence Agencies Read Overwritten Data?](https://www.nber.org/sys-admin/overwritten-data-guttman.html)
- [Secure deletion: a single overwrite will do it](https://web.archive.org/web/20130222073523/http://www.h-online.com/newsticker/news/item/Secure-deletion-a-single-overwrite-will-do-it-739699.html)